# JS Focus on hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to focus on the first result from a google search query (ie tab tab tab until you can hit Enter and go into the first result)

> var firstResult = document.getElementsByClassName("g")[0];  //.focus()

How do you focus on the hyperlink so that clicking Enter lets you into the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right. You just need to call the focus() method on your variable. Like this:

```js
var firstResult = document.getElementsByClassName('g')[0];
firstResult.focus();
```

```html
<a class="g" href="#">link1</a>
<a class="g" href="#">link2</a>
<a class="g" href="#">link3</a>
```

Comment: Alright I figured out the problem. My Tampermonkey script wasn't running on the google site. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that with window.onload function as:-

```
window.onload = function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByClassName("mylinkclass")[0].focus()
}
```